# MYSQL Update Syntax error with string input

Tags: php, mysql

my code below

```
    $count++;
    $yesstring = 'MATCH';

    echo $count . '. RESULT ' . $idcheck . ': ' . $phonecheck . ' was matched. <br />';

    $matchquery = sprintf("UPDATE `list` SET match = `%s` WHERE homephone = `%s` LIMIT 1",
        mysql_real_escape_string($yesstring),
        mysql_real_escape_string($phonecheck));

    $matchresult = mysql_query($matchquery);

    if (!$matchresult) {
        die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
    }
```

and this is my error

Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match = `MATCH` WHERE homephone = `(999) 999-9999` LIMIT 1' at line 1

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL. Escape it with backticks:

```
 UPDATE `list` SET `match` = ...
```

Comment: That did it.  I had no idea.   Swapped out the column name and this all good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You're using backticks when you should be using regular quotes. Backticks are reserved for escaping table or column names:

```
INSERT INTO `foo` VALUES ('value')
```

Although you're properly escaping your SQL, calling `mysql_real_escape_string` can prove to be a constant nuisance. Switching to `mysqli` or PDO would make writing correct SQL a lot easier in the long-run.